# Java printf for sum and average

Tags: java, printf

This is what I have:

```
  double[] miles = new double [10];

  double milesPerWeek = 26.0 / 10;
  double totalMiles = 0;
  double sum = 0;
  double average = 0;

  System.out.println("Week\tMiles");

  for (int i = 0; i < miles.length; i++){

     miles[i] += milesPerWeek;
     totalMiles += miles[i];

     System.out.printf("Week %d\t%.1f%n", i + 1, totalMiles);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < miles.length; i++)
  {              
     sum = sum + miles[i];
     average = sum / miles.length;
  }
  System.out.printf("The total of miles run is: %.1f%n" + sum + "\n");

  System.out.printf("The average of miles run is: %.1f%n" + average);
```

This is the problem I'm having with sum and average.  I cannot seem to format the decimal places using print f without this error message:
     The total of miles run is: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.1f'

Can you please direct me as I need one decimal place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the values as arguments, not concat them:

```
System.out.printf("The total of miles run is: %.1f%n\n", sum);

System.out.printf("The average of miles run is: %.1f%n", average);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Blah %.1f\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that moment where there is an Ah Ha!!!  I just had it...plus signs are not to be used in formating your output...commas are!
Corrected syntax:

```
System.out.printf("The total of miles run is: %.1f%n", sum, "\n");

System.out.printf("The average of miles run is: %.1f%n", average);
```

Comment: `%n` s not placeholder for *your own* line separators. It is placeholder for *OS* line separator. So there is no point in adding second `"\n"` as parameter since it will not be used in your `printf`.